# Angularjs ng-disabled + radioSelected

Tags: angularjs

```
<input type="radio" name="ptype" value="{{a}}" ng-model="group" checked>
<div class="row" id="{{a}}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="group" value="1" id="btype" ng-options="idBankCard as vcBankCardDesc.vcDescription for (idBankCard, vcBankCardDesc) in b.status" name="idGroup" ng-disabled="group== 2">
            <option value="">--Please Select Payment--</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have two select options. When I select option 1 then option 2 should be disabled. I tried many way but still cannot work...Anyone can give me solution?

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: <input type="radio" name="ptype" value="{{a}}" ng-model="group" checked >
                   
 

<div  class="row" id="{{a}}">
 <div class="form-group">               
 <select class="form-control" ng-model="group" value="1" id="btype" ng-options="idBankCard as vcBankCardDesc.vcDescription for (idBankCard, vcBankCardDesc) in b.status" name="idGroup" ng-disabled="group== 2" >
  <option value="">--Please Select Payment--</option>
 </select>
 </div> 
</div>

Comment: I get the value from database so that have 2 value is inside database. value= {{a}} have value=1 & value=2.

Comment: please put your code in your question not in comment